# Is the zero element and zero vector the same thing in the context of Linear Independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say..

A finite set of elements from a linear space are linearly independent if:

1. Their trivial linear combination is equal to the zero element
2. Their trivial linear combination is equal to the zero vector

I am not sure if statements 1 and 2 say the same thing.

I know that the zero element has the properties; for elements x and y of a linear space :

x + zero element = x

x + y = zero element

And I believe a zero vector would be an n tuple with only zero elements: (0,0,...,0)

Right now I believe they are the same thing in terms of properties that they have when talking about linear spaces and I think it is just different terminology.

But I also know from an example of a field with 2 elements (even and odd) that, even is the zero element in the field and it is not an n tuple with only zero elements.

As even + even = even and even + odd = odd

Comment: Other objects besides tuples of numbers can be vectors, and even if you’re working with tuples of numbers, depending on the vector addition and scalar multiplication in use, the all-zero tuple might not be the “zero vector.”

Comment: even * odd = odd ?

Comment: @glockm15 -- I hope you know that $x+y=0$ is not true in general! What is true is that, for all $x$, there exists some $y$ such that $x+y=0$ . In other words, opposites exist.

Comment: My point is that "for elements $x$ and $y$" is not quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your definitions are wrong. It should be, if the set is $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$,

> $$\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_iv_k=0 \;\Rightarrow\;\text{all $\lambda_i=0$.}$$

You are correct that the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has exactly $n$ entries that are equal to the real number $0$.

Finally, the terms zero element and zero vector are often used interchangeably in this context.

Comment: Thanks @max_zorn ,So would it be correct in this context to say that 0 is the zero element/zero vector

Answer (score 1):

The most conscise definition of vector space is:

> an abelian group on which a field acts

The zero vector of such a vector space is nothing else but the zero (or neutral) element of said abelian group.
Specifically, in the vector space $F^n$ of $n$-tuples of elements of the field $F$, the zero vector is also the tuple with all entries zero, $(0,0,\ldots,0)$.

Noe however, that we always also have the ground field in the context of vector spaces. The additive group of that filed of course *also* has a zero element, which (unless we consider the field as vector space over itself) is *not* referred to as zero vector.